# PayPal how to get library version?

Tags: android, paypal

I am looking to access the version of the PayPal library on Android, for logging/debugging purposes.

On iOS one can get the PayPal library version like so:

```
[PayPalMobile libraryVersion]
```

How do we retrieve the PayPal library version on Android? I've searched the docs but have found no reference to it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The version of the PayPal Android SDK is returned in the payment response (see sample here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).

Comment: That is true but that is not what i am looking for. The iOS version of the sdk allows you to retrieve this information without relying on the response. If the api is consistent across platforms it should offer this functionality on android also.